# behavioural equivalent of NOSCALE in Oracle 12c R1

Tags: oracle12c

Oracle 12c R2 introduces the concept of `NOSCALE` to its sequence creation script options.

What is the equivalent option for `NOSCALE` in 12c R1? i.e. if I just leave it off of my script in R1, will I get the same behaviour? Or is there some other option I need to specify? What differences will I notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, what was introduced is the concept of `SCALE` i.e. scalability. `NOSCALE` specifies the default behaviour.  In 12c R1 you have no option but the default, effectively `NOSCALE`.